# Magento 2 layout_render takes long time to execute

Tags: magento2

I have a multistore freshly installed (ca. 100 simple products on one store, the other is empty) on a shared hosting server and it went from a situation where it was fast and usable to incredibly slow, in a matter of a day. No significant changes were made so I can't understand the problem.

Enabling the profiler shows that `magento->LAYOUT->layout_render` takes more than 25 seconds to execute, both in admin and frontend.

CPanel shows limitations on CPU usage and I/O usage.

Could you put me in the right way to debug the problem?

**UPDATE EDIT**: the slow behavior was due to the merging and minify options of js and css set to Yes in the configuration

Comment: Can you check if the multistore is still in developer mode? Because if it is these options might slow down your loading since (what i understand) it will create the .min.css and .min.js every time you load a page. It needs to be in production mode

Comment: i just upgraded from magento 2.1 to 2.2, and layout_render is 7 times slower than magento 2.1

Answer (score 3):

We had this same problem too. We were able to work around this issue by setting Magento Config > Advanced > Developer > CSS Settings > Merge CSS Files = No.

We did not see this issue with these other configs set to yes:
Minify CSS Files = Yes
Merge JavaScript Files = Yes
Enable JavaScript Bundling = Yes
Minify JavaScript Files = Yes

We saw 10 second slow down on product and category pages. We did not notice this behavior on the home page.

Comment: Can I ask if you tested this in developer or production mode?

Comment: I have the same issue, nobody clarify this behavior https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/161337/magento-2-slow-in-developer-mode-with-js-css-merge-minimize-bundling-configur